# Suma de inputs y resta con resultado automático

Tags: javascript, html

Hola tengo este código que realiza la suma de los inputs que tienen la clase monto y muestra el resultado automáticamente en el input total, pero necesito que detecte si el ultimo input que tiene la clase resta tiene valor y luego reste dicho valor a la suma de los inputs anteriores.

```
function sumar()
{
  const $total = document.getElementById('total');
  let subtotal = 0;
  [ ...document.getElementsByClassName( "monto" ) ].forEach( function ( element ) {
    if(element.value !== '') {
      subtotal += parseFloat(element.value);
    }
  });
  $total.value = subtotal;
}

<span>Valor #1</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #2</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #3</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />

<span>Valor #4</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_4" class="restar" onchange="sumar();" />

<hr>
<span>TOTAL </span>
<input type="number" id="total" value="0" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Capturas a tu input `txt_campo_4` y almacenarlo en una variable.
- Inicializas una variable (llamado `valueResta`) para asignar su valor si el valor de `txt_campo_4` es diferente a vacío, de lo contrario, será `0`.
- Creamos una variable `total` en el que su valor será el `subtotal` menos el `valueResta`, y le asignas al valor del input `$total`.

---

#### Demo:

```js
function sumar() {
  const $total = document.getElementById('total');
  const restaInput = document.getElementById("txt_campo_4");
  
  let subtotal = 0;
  let valueResta = 0;
  
  [ ...document.getElementsByClassName( "monto" ) ].forEach( function ( element ) {
    if(element.value !== '') {
      subtotal += parseFloat(element.value);
    }
  });

  if (restaInput.value !== '') {
    valueResta = parseFloat(restaInput.value);
  }

  const total = subtotal - valueResta;

  $total.value = total;
}
```

```html
<span>Valor #1</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #2</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #3</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />

<span>Valor #4</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_4" class="restar" onchange="sumar();" />

<hr>
<span>TOTAL </span>
<input type="number" id="total" value="0" readonly/>
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias :)